Do multiple mouse click & move tasks at the same time
I'm trying to make it so that I can click and move the mouse to do different things at the same time. An example would be this where I want to get the mouse to draw 2 boxes at the same time. No, I can't draw them separately one by one.
I tried using threads (both threading and ThreadPoolExecutor) and multiprocessing but since there's only 1 mouse pointer it gets teleported back and forth and the result looks like this
I've only found one post on this topic and it doesn't have any answers, help would be appreciated.

You can't do that, operating systems only allow 1 mouse pointer to exist, apps that simulate the existance of a second mouse don't allow dragging, because the operating system doesn't, or at least you would be limited to only 1 dragging pointer at the same time because that would be the real mouse pointer. If this is however a drawing app you are authoring then you need to emulate this behavior in the application code yourself.

The answer is YES. You can do. I do have  sample. You don't need Thread.

@toyotaSupra Can you tell me how or give me src code I can work with?

I am searching on my harddrive.. Actually, I do have triangle, but I couldn't find square rectangle.

@toyotaSupra Alright, if you can't find the rectangle ones send the triangle ones I'll probably figure something out.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
